# Show only the error, not the page content

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to prevent abusive large file uploads, so I'm experimenting with the Apache configurations.

Normally, Apache waits for the file to upload, and then throws a warning about the large file upload. This is not practical. Why should one waste bandwidth on invalid large uploads? I've came accross the [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive. This seems to work as expected. It terminates the connection if the file exceeds the limit.

While this directive solves the connection problem, it also causes one. I have the following simple setup. I simply pick a file and upload it. Apache terminates the connection if I upload a large file.

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, the problem is the error output. It throws/outputs a `413 Request Entity Too Large` error, but the output is prepended to the page's content, that is, I see both the error output and the upload form. For example:

```html
<h1>Request entity too large!</h1>
<p>
    The POST
    method does not allow the data transmitted, or the data volume
    exceeds the capacity limit.
</p>
<p>
If you think this is a server error, please contact
the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.
</p>
<h2>Error 413</h2>
<address>
  <a href="/">localhost</a><br>
  <span>Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1f PHP/7.4.4</span>
</address>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Ideally, I would want to output only the error, not the page's content. To get around this, I thought about setting a custom error document (a PHP file) and `exit`/`die` in it. For example:

```
LimitRequestBody 2097152
ErrorDocument 413 /error/too_large.php
```

and in the `too_large.php`:

```php
<?php
echo "<p>File too large.</p>";
exit;
die;
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work. It just prepends the error output to the page's content:

```html
<p>File too large.</p>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

What am I missing here? Can't I just output the error?

---

Test case:

`page.php`

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

`httpd.conf`

```
LimitRequestBody 2097152
ErrorDocument 413 /error/too_large.php
```

`too_large.php`

```php
<?php

echo "<p>File too large.</p>";

exit;
die;
```

Also, here's a screenshot that summarizes the situation.

[image: screenshot of the page and the code]

**Update**

I've installed the latest XAMPP (8.0.6) and tested this again. The result is the same. Next, I'll be testing this on a live server. I can't do it right now, because there seems to be other problems with the bitnami LAMP stack, so I'm waiting a reply from the bitnami team.

**Update 2**

I'm still in talks with the bitnami team, and today I noticed that it's started working as expected on my local machine. I get only the error document output. That wasn't the case before (with both the new and old versions of XAMPP). The only thing that might have changed is that restarting of the computer. I don't know what to make of this. Since the question is no longer relevant, I might delete this later.

Although, the same problem occurs in the bitnami LAMP stack. `LimitRequestBody` directive doesn't seem to work (fully). If anyone wants to follow the problem: [LimitRequestBody returns 200 OK](https://community.bitnami.com/t/php-file-upload-limit-change-doesnt-take-effect-until-reboot/95956)

---

<sup>I'm on Windows 10 x64, and using XAMPP 7.4.4.</sup>

Comment: Can you turn the message into a variable in too_large.php and then echo the variable on the form page if you want and in the desired spot?

Comment: You can't execute PHP in an HTML file.

Comment: "the output is prepended to the page's content" no, that's not how it works, unless you've got some Ajax going on. If the server returns 413, it does not continue processing PHP or anything else.

Comment: @miken32 Are you absolutely sure? Here's a [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/c2qrjXv/Annotation-2021-05-27-232733.png).

Comment: I stand corrected, I wasn't aware that the value of ErrorDocument was a URL; it's been a few years since I worked with Apache full time though.

Comment: @Kinglish I rather not depend on the page content to handle the Apache's shortcoming. One can try to upload a file to an any page. I'd have to implement the same solution in every page.

Comment: can you share your code logic to upload file, and it's not a good idea to set upload size limit in your .htaccess file or confd

Comment: @butalin Updated the question with code/details.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but you could use apache or the `too_large.php` file to redirect the user to another page, for example, you could host `example.com/error/file-to-large` were you redirect the user to, this way you have 100% control over the content. Anyway recommend asking on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) since this is more network related then programming.

Comment: Anything we know so far, still doesn’t explain why the error document should contain your form again. IMHO this only makes sense, if your are not actually leaving the current page you are on, but the request was made via JS in the background, and then the server response gets inserted into the current document. Or there must be something else going on, that we have not been told about yet.

Comment: @CBroe AFAIK, there's nothing to tell, really. I'm going to test the same thing on a live server (AWS), but I'm having an `ErrorDocument` issue on the server. When I upload a large file that exceeds the limit, the server doesn't even return `413`. It returns `200`. Once I clear these issues and and test the custom error page, I'll update the question. Also will test this with a different XAMPP version on the local environment. Maybe it's specific the this version.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including your logic to upload the file to your server, so i'll improvise,

first **you cannot get size of file using a server side language if the file is not on that server**, means you must upload the file before check it size.

sounds bad answer, but there is JavaScript, it's a front end technology, and front end language can do the job

so to work around this problem let's disable the submit button until we have a desired file size and enable it, result also in a better user experience, let me show you how it's easy

first add some ids to your input and button, and make button disabled like so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
    <button disabled="true" id="submitButton" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

then add some js code inside `<script>` tags

```
<script>
   //your js code goes here
</script>
```

first thing to do is to select the button and input elements and store there references into two variables

```
 var submit = document.querySelector('#submitButton');

 var file = document.querySelector('#file');
```

now let's listen whenever our file input changes, for that we add an event listener with a callback function:

```
file.addEventListener('change', function(event){

       //logic to check file size

    })
```

here the callback function has an argument is `event`, this object stores a lot of information about the change event, but the most important is to get the file size, we create a new variable and assign to it the file size destructed from the event object like so:

```
var filesize = event.target.files[0].size/1000
```

size is in bytes divided by 1000 results in KB

then we do the check so if you wan to upload files less than 4MB means `filesize < 4000`

```
if(filesize < 4000){
   //enable button
}else{
   //keep button disabled and alert user
}
```

to enable the button we use the button variable (submit) declared in first place:

```
submit.disabled = false;
```

and if size is bigger alert user with a message, and clear the file input

```
alert('file too large')
file.value = ''
```

**the final result :**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
    <button disabled="true" id="submitButton" >Submit</button>
</form>

<script>

    var submit = document.querySelector('#submitButton');

    var file = document.querySelector('#file');

    file.addEventListener('change', function(event){
        
        var filesize = event.target.files[0].size/1000;

        if(filesize < 4000){
            //enable button
            submit.disabled = false;
        }else{
            //keep button disabled and alert user
            alert('file too large');
            file.value = ''
        }   
    })

</script>
```

Comment: But this is client sided right? Guess OP is looking for a server sided solution.

Comment: i have already mentioned that in my answer : first you cannot get size of file using a server side language if the file is not on that server, means you must upload the file before check it size.

Comment: There's no logic. The page/form is exactly the way I posted in the question. This code is not from production... And yes, you can get the request body size in the content-length header. I think you misunderstood the problem. I don't care about individual files. One can upload multiple files. All file sizes summed up in the content-length header. So this has nothing to do with the client.

Comment: How you are uploading files? Yes i misunderstood your question, can't find how exactly you are uploading files to server normal you should post your data to php and the var $_FILES['file']['size' ] is the header you are talking about

Comment: "How?" I have a simple form there. I'm not using anything extra... Anyway. Thank you for your attempts, but it's obvious that we're having a miscommunication here, and it doesn't seem to get better. So I doubt that I'll be participating in this further.